# How do you store a character in a list of linked lists in C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am trying to create a list of linked lists, but i get a warning:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("Data in 0 is : %s\n",list[0]->data);
```

the code is below

```
create(0,'A');
printf("Data in 0 is : %s\n",list[0]->data);
```

the create() code:

```
void create(int indx, char rsc){
    struct Node* tmp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp->data = rsc;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    list[indx] = tmp;
```

the list of Nodes is initialized as follows:

```
struct Node *list[26];
```

Comment: And the definition of `struct Node` is...

Comment: It seems to me that your `data` member is a char, but you are trying to print it as a string, with `%s`.

Comment: Perhaps use `%c` instead of `%s`.

Comment: thanks, it worked by changing '%s' to '%d'